# Access USB serial ports using Python and pyserial

Tags: python, macos, serial-port, usb, pyserial

How do I access the USB port using pyserial? I have seen an [example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13665/what-is-the-simplest-and-cheapest-way-to-interface-with-usb/13678#13678) with:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
```

I used to access the serial port from MATLAB on Windows and using the appropriate syntax, `/dev/ttyUSB0` would be replaced by `COM1` or any other COM port.

I'm on a Mac and I tried using the [serial port scanners](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/examples.html#finding-serial-ports) on the `pyserial` documentation to no avail. I think I should write it like this:

```
import serial

name = ? # Names of serial ports on Mac OS X
ser = serial.Serial(name)
```

How do I find out what `name` should be on a Mac?

**EDIT:** In response to an answer below, I'd like to find out how to access both USB to RS232 converters as well as pure USB ports.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only access USB Serial Adapters using pyserial (i.e., USB RS-232 dongles).  If you want generic USB access you should be looking into "libusb".  If it is RS-232 you are trying to access through USB then you should look for a file in /dev starting with cu.usb* (/dev/cu.usbserial-181 for example).

Comment: Even while using Houdini to display hidden files and folders, `/dev` is a symbolic link without anything inside. I tried using Finder's Go to Folder and I'd get "The folder can't be found". How do I get around this?

Comment: try `ls -l /dev/cu.usb*` from a terminal window

Comment: Nothing like `cu.usb` at all. I do find `cu.Kit-COM1`, and only that. But the Macbook Pro has two USB ports on the left side (and possible more hidden ones used by the keyboard and other built-ins).

Comment: Only USB ports that have an RS-232 adapter plugged in will appear as /dev/cu.whatever (that is the cu.Kit-COM1 in your case).  USB is *not* serial in the traditional sense of the word.  It is far more high-tech than that.

Answer (score 3):

To find the available ports you can use `serial.tools` (which is part of the `pyserial` library, but needs to be imported separately). The device name can then be found using the `.device` method. This works for me on Mac:

```py
from serial.tools import list_ports
port = list(list_ports.comports())
for p in port:
    print(p.device)
```

For more on `list_ports`, see: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#module-serial.tools.list_ports